# python ipdb.set_trace() one frame "up" (frame=?)

Tags: python, ipdb

Sometimes when I invoke ipdb, I *know* I want to be a frame above where the trace is set. I presume that's why the API exposes the `frame` parameter (as discussed in [the documentation](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/blob/master/ipdb/__main__.py)).

So here's the function:

```
import inspect, ipdb

def invoke_a_frame_up():
   ipdb.set_trace(frame=inspect.stack()[i][0])
```

I'm trying to figure out what *i* is in the function so that, when `invoke_a_frame_up` gets called, the trace is not *inside* `invoke_a_frame_up`.

Or, more aptly, I'm trying to figure out how to achieve this generally. I've tried every i for the depth of the stack and the trace seems to start at the same frame regardless, until i is greater than the depth, at which point I get `IndexError('list index out of range',)`.

Comment: Is there something wrong with just doing `up` command?

Comment: @HaPsantran You should create your answer below, and mark it as accepted if it works for you. Do not edit your questions to include an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import inspect
import ipdb

def dbg_up():
    ipdb.set_trace(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back)

def foo():
    var = 'in foo'
    bar()

def bar():
    var = 'in bar'
    dbg_up()

foo()
```

Users of vanilla `pdb`: your interface is slightly different, like this:

```
pdb.Pdb().set_trace(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your example works for me too, but when I add quit() *after* the set_trace() call, I do not get the desired result anymore. I'll edit my question to further explain.